# How is this off topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Information Security Stack Exchange post: [USB Drive for Bad USB](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/205906/usb-drive-for-bad-usb)

How is that post off topic? I asked about a device used for pen testing.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but you can try asking this is in hardware recommendations Stack Exchange site: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8):

I have explained this numerous times in comments.

You are asking which devices on Amazon have a certain chipset. This is not a security question. You want to know because you want to choose one to develop BadUSB, but your *question* is not security related.

And, and I also explained, questions of the type "what products have X?" are off-topic because they are open-ended and the list could go on forever.

Comment: You are trying to frame it as only looking for a random chipset.  That isn't the case. I am looking for a usb drive I can use for BadUSB. That is a security issue.

Comment: I never said "random chipset", but that does not matter. Looking for a particular chipset has the same problem.

Comment: I didn't say that you said random chipset. I said that you make it sound like sending I am only sending people to find a random chipset and it is not security related. I found the right chipset myself, for a 100% security related task, but just want to know if Kingston used the same chipset across all variations of that model of usb drive.

Comment: Look at it this way: let's say I know 5 devices on Amazon that can be used for BadUSB. I answer with a list of those 5 things. Is that an answer? Then someone else comes by and lists 10 more. Then next year, more vendors produce new devices with the chipset. Now there's a new answer with those devices, but the old devices are no longer sold. Do you see the problem? The answers are never ending and constantly changing. That makes this sort of question a bad fit for a Q&A site.

Comment: So you see, it doesn't matter if you are looking for a security-related chipset. The problem has nothing to do with the relevance of the chipset you are looking for.

Comment: That example does not fit. Yes it is opened ended if you keep adding new devices, but that is not what is happening here for this reason. 
1. I identified a specific model of USB Drive, the Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 T111 8GB. 
Even if new drives come along, they would not be the same Kingston DataTraveler and therefore the question would not be open ended. I wanted to know if the different variations of that **bold**singular**bold** model use different chip sets. That makes the question not opened ended in the manor you described.

Comment: You accused me of reframing your question, but you keep doing it yourself. None of this is what you have asked. You asked if we knew for sure which products on Amazon are this chipset. Not what products Kingston have made that have this chipset. And for *what you asked* it follows the example. There might not be newly made products but vendors may add and take away inventory. The resulting answers remain open-ended. Not only that, but different region's Amazon stores will have different selection.

Comment: I'm sorry this site does not work the way you want it to, but beating this dead horse is not going to get the question more in line with the guidelines of the site.

Comment: You said I asked which products on Amazon have that chipset, not what products Kingston made with that chipset. That proves you didn't read it. I named the exact model of Kingston drive in my question, if you would read it.

Comment: "Does anyone here know for sure which USB drive on Amazon has the right chipset?" I'm now finished with this conversation.

Comment: Yes, the usb drive on Amazon was in reference to the sentence before it , wherein I named the exact model I wanted. Lol. "When I search for Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 T111 8GB, multiple USB drives from Kingston come up." That shows you didn't read it.

Comment: Since you admit using that drive for pen testing is security related how would you want someone to ask about it?